# How to get xpath for this element

Tags: selenium, xpath

1. I have lot of tr tag with same structure in my page . The only way to select "Google" is by starting the XPATH from "ImgTrash.png" . Please let me know if you have idea .

   ```
     <tr>
      <td width="1%"/>
         <td class="Fol" nowrap="" style="padding-left: 0px">
            <a id="A57" href="3745474">
                 <img src="ImgTrash.png"/>
                 <span style="vertical-align:middle">Trash </span>                     
              </a>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Row">
       <td width="1%"/>
       <td class="Fol" nowrap="" style="padding-left: 8px">
           <a id="A56" href="507023">
             <img  src="ImgFolder.png"/>
             <span style="vertical-align:middle">Google  </span>                                                                             
          </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
   ```

Comment: are you using webdriver or RC etc ??.Please provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an XPath like this:

```
//a[img/@src = 'ImgFolder.png']/span
```

Breakdown:

- `//a` searches for all `<a>` elements
- `[img/@src = 'ImgFolder.png']` only selects the `<a>` elements that have a child `<img>` with the attribute `src`. This attribute `src` should exactly match (case-sensitive) `ImgFolder.png`
- `/span` at the end will get the child `<span>` from the previous selected `<a>`